# How to use the RadContinuumAnimation in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, telerik

I'm using the RadContinuumAnimation from Telerik inside of my Windows Phone 7 application on a listbox. Now when you get the controls the do give an example which you can download from telerik on how to use it but they hardcode it so it only lets you select the first item.

Ironically when I used it on my listbox in my application it allowed me to select an item in my listbox and it behaved properly but everytime the animation took place it ALWAYS animates the first item.

I found this [post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/windows-phone/phoneapplicationframe/how-to-use-continuum-animation-with-databoundlistbox.aspx) in Telerik forums, but I haven't been able to make much out of it. I tried the setting the ContinuumElement to the SelectedItem but it threw this error:

> 'MyApp_2011.Model.MenuItem' is not a valid value for property 'ContinuumElement'.

I'm guessing that it has to be a control such as a Textblock but I'm not sure how to access the textblock since the listbox is databound. Does someone with more experience understand why this might be happening or how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you basically need to do this

```
if (!(this.continuumElement is TextBlock)) 
            { 
                TextBlock textBlock = ElementTreeHelper.FindVisualDescendant<TextBlock>(this.continuumElement); 

                if (textBlock != null) 
                { 
                    this.continuumElement = textBlock; 
                } 
            }
```

In your `ListBox`'s `SelectionChanged` event.

```
private void YourListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess where I'm getting confused is what is "continuumElement"? Is that the transition that I made in XAML?

Comment: continuumElement is the element that when you click on the item, it flies to the right. Take the gmail app in wp for example, the continuumElement is the subject of the email.

Comment: Perfect, it all makes sense now and it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Just remember to reset the `SelectedIndex` back to -1, without doing this when you navigate back to your list page and click the same item it won't navigate. :)